# 12^10 = 61917ab4224. Find the missing terms; use mod 9 and mod 11.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Not sure how to go about this. I add up the numbers since divisible by 9 and got 36+a+b then for mod 11 did alternating and got b-a+20...help please!

Comment: umm... the rest is a trivial pair of linear equations in two variables

Comment: Why was there negative vote, when on one liners, with no computation, get tens and hundreds of up-votes.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  So based on divisibility by $9$ you have $a+b=0$ or $9$, since their sum must be a multiple of $9$.  What is $12^{10} \pmod {11}?$  You have $b-a+20 \equiv $ that $\pmod {11}$  Now solve the two equations.